Spark/Pyspark how to set a property using spark.conf.set
Would like to know the exact syntax (in Pyspark)for setting some property using spark.conf.set. I have seen multiple ways but not sure what's the correct way.
Suppose I want to set spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled, now which syntax is correct

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled", True)
spark.sql("set adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=true")
spark.sql("set adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled=True")


According to this page in the documentation, you can use lower case "true". As in pyspark you use the spark.conf.set command, this mean that your first option should be correct. You can also refer to this documentation, seeing that you have to provide key and value in string format.
If you dive into the code, then you see that the value is converted to string, so your second option might work as well, but I am not sure how the upper case will influence things.
To check whether you were successful, you can run the following.
spark.conf.get("spark.sql.adaptive.optimizeSkewsInRebalancePartitions.enabled")

typo in your last code line. Should be “get” instead of “set”
